# Data cleansing with cassandra and pig

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig, datastax-enterprise

I have two sets of data that i would like to compare in Pig. Both have the same unique IDs with the names in the 2nd set of data randomly changed. The logic as follows:

- load empl1 raw data
- load empl2 raw data
- select row where 'names are not the same' and 'emplno is equal'

I have done:

```
A1=  LOAD 'cassandra://employees_pig1/employees_cf' USING CassandraStorage() AS (key, columns: bag {T: tuple(name, value)});

B1=  LOAD 'cassandra://employees_pig2/employees_cf' USING CassandraStorage() AS (key, columns: bag {T: tuple(name, value)});

A2 = FOREACH A1 GENERATE key, FLATTEN(columns);

B2 = FOREACH B1 GENERATE key as key2, FLATTEN(columns);
```

heh, can't post images in the forum. here's the link for illustrate A2,B2
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/SU3QgKsbA4nmq83cdnhiVdMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Need some help now, am i approaching this correctly?

```
C1 = join A2 by key, B2 by key2;

D1= filter C1 by A2.key==B2.key2 -- cannot do a A2.first_name!=B2.first_name;
```

would like to do the  *select row where 'names are not the same' and 'emplno is equal'* but not entirely sure how. pls advise.

thank u

Update:
- instead of a join i did a cogroup
    C3= COGROUP A2 by key, B2 by key2;

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/_lkEqW4BvIgbnZSHKDCJGNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

next, am thinking of doing

```
D1= FOREACH C3 GENERATE group, A2.first_name as fn1, B2.first_name as fn2
```

the group returns the desired result (ie empno), but the 'A2.first_name, B2.first_name'are incorrect. Need to know how to access the data within A2 and B2 bags/tuples.

I would then be able to do a FILTER BY fn1==fn2.

Answer (score 1):

By doing a `JOIN` (at least, an inner join, which is what you have done above), you already take care of ensuring that the `emplno`s from `A` and `B` are equal.  Then all you have to do is filter by whether the `name`s are the same.

```
C1 = join A2 by key, B2 by key;
D1 = filter C1 by A2::name != B2::name;
```

Comment: thank u, but i've tried that and it does not work.


<pre>Error: Invalid field projection. Projected field [A2::first_name] does not exist in schema.<code>

Need some pointers how to access the data inside the columns:
<pre>
>describe A2
A2:{key:chararray,columns::name:chararray,colums::value:chararray}<code>

Comment: Why are you doing `A2::first_name` when the field in `A2` is called `name`?  `describe C1` after the `join` and you'll see what the fields are called so you form the filter correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved :)**

Steps:
- download pygmalion https://github.com/jeromatron/pygmalion/downloads

Quick test:

```
register '/usr/share/dse/pygmalion/pygmalion-1.0.0.jar';
define FromCassandraBag org.pygmalion.udf.FromCassandraBag();
define ToCassandraBag org.pygmalion.udf.ToCassandraBag();

A1=  LOAD 'cassandra://employees_pig1/employees_cf' USING CassandraStorage() AS (key,
columns: bag {T: tuple(name, value)});
B1=  LOAD 'cassandra://employees_pig2/employees_cf' USING CassandraStorage() AS (key, 
columns: bag {T: tuple(name, value)});

A2 = foreach A1 generate key,
flatten(org.pygmalion.udf.FromCassandraBag('first_name', columns))
as (first_name: chararray);

B2 = foreach B1 generate key,
flatten(org.pygmalion.udf.FromCassandraBag('first_name', columns))
as (first_name: chararray);

C1 = join A2 by key, B2 by key;
D1= filter C1 BY A2::first_name != B2::first_name;
```